# java xpath return unexpected values

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm builind an application which shows a map with the google api. Using the user input address, I query the API for directions to a destination. The API returns me a XML response which I parse to build my directions objects and show informations to the user.

Everything works but some of my `xpath.evaluate()` use do not work as I expect. For example this response :

[Google Maps Response](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=700%20Rue%20Wellington,%20Montreal,%20QC%20H3C%202P1,%20Canada&destination=1100,%20rue%20Notre-Dame%20Ouest&waypoints=optimize:true%7C1720,%20rue%20Saint-Denis&mode=driving&sensor=false)

When I use :

```
NodeList legList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//route/leg",
                    response, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Even `//leg`should do the job right?

When I do a legList.getLength(), it gives me 23 but there are only two leg in the response. Do you know why this strange behavior is happening? I read about [XML Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818532/parse-xml-with-xpath-namespaces-in-java) but I still don't know what to do, should I specidfy a namespace even if the answer doesn't contain any, and if yes, why do I have to?

Comment: For the given response `//leg` and `//route/leg` are equivalent. They're not necessarily equivalent in all possible responses. Have you tried `/route/leg`? What are the nodes in `legList`?

Comment: On my JVM (Sun JDK1.6.0_14), requesting XPathConstants.NODE, returns type: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl - which also implements the NodeList interface. So I believe it is reporting the length as the number of child nodes of the first <leg> element it found in the Xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
    NodeList legList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expr,
            xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a NodeList Use`XPathConstants.NODESET` instead of `XPathConstants.NODE` (check here for the mappings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#NODESET) like this:

```
NodeList legList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//route/leg", response, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: The think I don't understand is why the count gave me 23, the `<leg>` tag is a node right? I thought it would add every leg node it would find to the node list. But instead it looks like it added all of the children, am I right?

Comment: @David: See my comment above. Any element node from the Xml can present itself as a NodeList (which is an interface), because it can potentially have a list of child nodes. (Probably textNode type wouldn't implement NodeList, since it cannot have any children.)

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
NodeList legList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/route/leg",
                response, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

NODESET is return the NodeList while  XPathConstants.NODE is return single Object.